# Nuxt websockets Laravel Echo private channel auth not triggered

Tags: websocket, jwt, nuxt.js, laravel-echo, pusher-js

Im currently working on implementing websockets in my Nuxt App. I have a Laravel backend and im using Pusher and Laravel Echo. The problem is that, when trying to connect/subscribe to a private channel - as the client is authorized via the broadcast/auth endpoint the individual channel auth (**channels.php**) is not hit. So it is possible for a logged in user to access a private channel that they should not be able to access.

My code/configuration is as follows:

NUXT FRONTEND:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
echo: {
 broadcaster: 'pusher',
 key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
 cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
 forceTLS: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
 authModule: true,
 authEndpoint: `${process.env.API_URL}/broadcasting/auth`,
 connectOnLogin: true,
 disconnectOnLogout: true,
 auth: {
  headers: {
    'X-AUTH-TOKEN': process.env.API_AUTH_TOKEN
  }
 }
```

},

LARAVEL BACKEND:

**BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => [JWTAuthMiddleware::class]]);

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

**AuthController.php**

```
public function auth(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $pusher = new Pusher(
        config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'),
        config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'),
        config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id')
    );
    $auth = $pusher->socket_auth($request->input('channel_name'), $request->input('socket_id'));
    return ResponseHandler::json(json_decode($auth));
}
```

**ChatMessageEvent.php**

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('chat.' . $this->chatMessage->getChatId());
}
```

**channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel(
'chat.{chatId}',
function (JwtUserDTO $user, int $chatId) {
    Log::info('test');
    return false;
}
```

);

As you may have noticed, we use a JWT auth strategy which is stored on the client side - so we have no sessions. But as the authorization via the auth endpoint works it should be possible to guard the individual private channels via the channels.php routing ? But as i can see in the logs, it is never reached. Am i missing some configuration ? or why am i authorized solely on the auth endpoint and not also on the individual channels routes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found out that the issue was with my `AuthController.php` as I had implemented my own auth function - which made it work in order to authenticate the user to the private channel. Unfortunately this then resulted in not leviating the BroadcastServiceProvider. So the solution was:

```
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastController;

Route::post('broadcasting/auth', [BroadcastController::class, 'authenticate'])
        ->middleware(BroadcastMiddleware::class);
```

This will then use the Broadcast Facade and enable use of the channels.php for authenticating the user against the given channel.

I also had to add a middleware to set the authenticated user in the Laravel session as this is needed by the ServiceProvider.

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Closure $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    /** @var JwtUserDTO $jwt */
    $jwt = $request->get('jwt');
    // Set the user in the request to enable the auth()->user()
    $request->merge(['user' => $jwt]);
    $request->setUserResolver(function() use ($jwt) {
        return $jwt;
    });
    Auth::login($jwt);

    return $next($request);
}
```

And to do this the Model or DTO in my case had to implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface. Remember to add functionality for the `getAuthIdentifierName` and `getAuthIdentifier` to return the username and user id respectivly as this is also needed if you want to play with presences channels.